# SQL Query to get Matrix reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, reporting-services, pivot

My "FeedbackSummary" table structure is

```
GivenBy varchar(50)
GivenTo varchar(50)
Points  decimal(15, 2)
```

Sample Data

```
Alice   Janet   4.50
Alice   Bruce   3.50
Bruce   Alice   2.87
Bruce   Janet   4.75
Janet   Alice   5.45
Janet   Bruce   3.78
```

What I am trying to achieve

```
GivenBy_GivenTo Alice   Bruce   Janet
Alice           NULL    3.50    4.50    
Bruce           2.87    NULL    4.75
Janet           5.45    3.78    NULL
```

Platform: SQL Server 2005 & 2008

How this can be done using Pivot or any other techniques.
Can this be achieved using SQL Reporting Services easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just added the tsql and ssrs tags to this, because it's an issue that really relates to whether you handle this data in the client (SSRS) or on the server (T-SQL)

Comment: (and the right answer for dynamic pivoting is 'the client')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to use SSRS. Put a matrix there, with one column on the rows and one on the columns. You can pivot in a query (the PIVOT option), but that doesn't allow for flexibility in reporting.

Rob

Comment: Yes. I tested this data with SSRS with matrix. The report was perfect and even it allowed some customization. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT t.givenby,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.givento = 'Alice' THEN t.points ELSE NULL END) 'Alice',
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.givento = 'Bruce' THEN t.points ELSE NULL END) 'Bruce',
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.givento = 'Janet' THEN t.points ELSE NULL END) 'Janet'
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.givenby
```

Comment: Close, but you'd need to aggregate this, putting SUM() around each CASE statement, and grouping by GivenBy.

But this doesn't suit SSRS at all, because SSRS doesn't like dynamically appearing columns.

Comment: Corrected missing aggregate calls.  Create a stored proc for SSRS if need be - that's how my SSRS are.

Comment: Ok, and then you use a table to display it. But if you need a new column you need to change both your stored procedure (unless you use dynamic SQL) and your report (regardless of whether you use dynamic SQL or not).

Comment: @Rob: Yes, but it wouldn't change even if you use PIVOT.  That's the reality of turning columnar data into rows.

Comment: Correct. I said something like "You could use PIVOT, but best is to do it in SSRS for flexibility"

Comment: Thanks rexem. The query achieved the purpose. But SSRS offered the flexibility.